# How do you "receive" an Ajax Request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm pretty new to Ajax, as the question I'm about to ask probably makes painfully obvious.

The prof showed us how to send the ajax request to a class (to pop_machine.php, a class called machine), but he never showed us how to actually get that information inside the class so we can make use of it. I'm trying to send the type of pop from a button-click (goal of the program is to simulate a vending machine) to my machine class in my pop_machine.php file using ajax.
I know it is sent as a string. I've tried making a variable in pop_machine.php to accept the pop type, and then instantiating the machine object and passing it into a pop type property through a constructor, then alerting the pop type property outside the class, but no go. This is only one of the things I've tried, and nothing seems to work.
I've tried Googling this, and just cannot seem to find the answer. I know I'm probably going to hit myself upside the head when I'm told.
Thanks!

```
function ajaxFunction()
            {
                var ajaxRequest;
                try
                {
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        alert("Your browser is too old!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var $PopType = document.getElementById('PopType').value;
                var get_query = "?PopType=" + PopType;
                ajaxRequest.open("GET", "pop_machine.php" + get_query, true);
                ajaxRequest.send(null);
                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                        alert(ajaxRequest.readyState);
                    }
<?php

include "dispenser.php";
class machine
{
    private $dispenser;
    public $PopType;

    public function __construct($PopType) {
        $this->PopType = $PopType;
        //$PopType;
    }
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->dispenser = new dispenser($PopType);
        return 0;
    }
}
$PopType = $_GET['PopType'];
$machine = new machine($PopType);
alert($machine -> PopType);

?>
```

Comment: `"?PopType=" + $PopType;` not `"?PopType=" + PopType;`

Comment: Or `var PopType = document.getElementById('PopType').value;` instead of `var $PopType = document.getElementById('PopType').value;`. That part is Javascript, if I don't get wrong.